# How can I vertically offset a bullet or content in CSS?

Tags: html, css

See this image:
[image: Bullets]

It's a little off-kilter, and I'd like to move the content up, or the bullet itself down. I've tried padding, margin and positioning to no avail.

Comment: Preferably using http://jsfiddle.net or a similar site.

Comment: My code is pretty much identical to j08691's code in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `vertical-align` property on the list items. Possible values are:

```
baseline | sub | super | text-top | text-bottom | middle | top | bottom | <percentage> | <length>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xFJvT/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

​**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/c9d/check.png);
}
li {
    vertical-align:top;   
}
​
```

Comment: Top is the only one that works in that fiddle. :/ None of the specific measurements (percent and px) work.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to set `line-height` equal to the height of the image

Answer (score 1):

Use the vertical-align css property to positioning de image or the text in the line.

For instance:

```
IMG { vertical-align:middle}
```

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align